# Loop through columnames to format colums with R-Package formattable kableExtra (R dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr, kableextra, formattable

Hei,

To compare several variants of data I produced a HTML report.
Given a special catagory some indexes in the database should be the same. To detect errors / incorrect entries in the database I compare the different categories in a table.
For better reading, it would be fine, to have coloured tables. This can be done easily with the `formattable-Package`.

My dataset:

```
require(tidyverse)
require(formattable)
require(kableExtra)
require(knitr)
df1 <- data.frame(V1 = c(68,sample(c("J","N"),size=15,replace = TRUE)),
                  V2 = c(10,sample(c("J","N"),size=15,replace = TRUE)),
                  V3 = c(1,sample(c("J","N"),size=15,replace = TRUE))
                 )
```

It has - in this example - 3 differnt variants. Only one is recomended. It is supposed, that the variant with the highest N (=first entry in each Vx-Column) is the real one.

My formated table is produced with this code:

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(
    V2 = ifelse((as.character(V2) == as.character(V1)) == FALSE,
                cell_spec(V2, color = "red",bold = TRUE), 
                cell_spec(V2, color = "black",bold = FALSE)),
    V3 = ifelse((as.character(V3) == as.character(V1)) == FALSE,
                cell_spec(V3, color = "red",bold = TRUE), 
                cell_spec(V3, color = "black",bold = FALSE))
  ) %>%
  kable(format = "html", escape = FALSE) %>%
  kable_styling(c("striped", "condensed"), full_width = FALSE) %>%
  row_spec(1, bold = T, color = "white", background = "#D7261E")
```

Two questions:

1. How to `mutate` in a loop?

This is necessary because the different categories I have to investigate can have up to 18 different variants. In each dataset, V1 is everytime the reference variant.

2. As you can see (run the code!) the first line (the "N"s) is  coded in the wrong matter. Is it possible to compare from the second line on only (first line is set to TRUE by default)

This would be fine, because the first line is now formated in a matter that does not really make sense.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your two questions:

1. Instead of looping over the columns, you can use `mutate_all`
2. Just take a copy of the first column and `mutate` it back in later

I have first made your `cell_spec` calls into functions to reduce clutter in the code.

```r
  red   <- function(x) cell_spec(x, color = "red", bold = TRUE)
  black <- function(x) cell_spec(x, color = "black", bold = FALSE)
  c1    <- as.character(df1[[1]])
```

Now we can do this:

```r
  df1                                                                           %>% 
  select(-V1)                                                                   %>%
  mutate_all(function(x) ifelse(as.character(x) != df1[[1]], red(x), black(x))) %>%
  mutate(V1 = black(c1))                                                        %>%
  mutate_all(function(x) `[<-`(x, 1, " "))                                      %>%
  select(V1, V2, V3)                                                            %>%
  kable(format = "html", escape = FALSE)                                        %>%
  kable_styling(c("striped", "condensed"), full_width = FALSE)                  %>%
  row_spec(1, bold = T, color = "white", background = "#D7261E")
```

Which gives this result:
[image]

Comment: Regarding the first column - first line is meant :-)

Comment: @VolkerHolzendorf OK, try the changed version

Comment: @VolkerHolzendorf Actually, you can use `mutate_all` instead of needing to load `purrr`. Answer updated. Does it answer your question?

Comment: I think I solved my problem - your hint to purrr::map_dfc was the thing I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @VolkerHolzendorf if my answer helped you, please consider accepting it so that others with similar problems can find their way to the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, @AllanCameron!

I 'm not familiar to the package `purrr` - I really should do more studies about it.

Your idea with `purrr::map_dfc` solved the problem.

Instead of the first column I need the first row (the digit-row), and of course with `grepl` it is possible to solve this. The condition in the `ifelse`-Statement is a little bit longer then.

My final solution is then:

```
df1 %>% 
  map_dfc(function(x) ifelse(as.character(x) != as.character(df1$V1) & !grepl("[[:digit:]]",x), 
                             mark_true(x), mark_false(x))) %>%
  select(V1, everything()) %>%
  kable(format = "html", escape = FALSE) %>%
  kable_styling(c("striped", "condensed"), full_width = FALSE) %>%
  row_spec(1, bold = T, color = "white", background = "#D7261E")
```

Thank you very much!